Qiskit not efficiently compiling with new gate basis
I am using Qiskit to compile a small Qiskit circuit (shown below) with a gate basis consisting of Rigetti native gates:

RZ
RX(±)
RX(±/2)
ISWAP.

I have followed the Qiskit guide to setting up a new basis:

create classes for the new gates
create a Target, specifying which gates are available on which qubits, edges etc.
specify gate equivalences.

The circuit compiles correctly, but the translation from standard Qiskit gates to the new basis seems to be inefficient. For example, with optimization_level=3, the translated circuit (shown below) contains:

4 x ISWAPs
50 x RZs
22 x RX(π/2)
22 x RX(-π/2).

If I compile the same circuit to the same gate basis using Rigetti's quilc compiler, the translated circuit (shown below) contains:

4 x ISWAPs
14 x RZs
5 x RX(π/2)
3 x RX(-π/2).

The compilation using Qiskit uses a lot more gates. What can I do to improve the Qiskit compilation (i.e. reduce the gate count)?
I have shown a subset of my code below, demonstrating how I create the gate classes and equivalences.
Notes:
I am using Qiskit 1.1.1 (there were limitations in compiling to new gate bases in older versions - see this post)
Example showing how I create a new gate class:
class NativeRXppion2Gate(Gate):
    def __init__(self, label: Optional[str] = "RX(π/2)"):
        super().__init__("Native_RX(π/2)", 1, [], label=label)

    def _define(self):
        q = QuantumRegister(1, "q")
        qc = QuantumCircuit(q, name=self.name)
        qc += (RXGate(np.pi / 2), [q[0]], [])
        self.definition = qc

    def control():
        <definition provided, but omitted for brevity>

    def inverse(self, annotated: bool = False):
        <definition provided, but omitted for brevity>


    def __array__(self, dtype=np.complex_):
        cos = np.cos(np.pi / 4)
        sin = np.sin(np.pi / 4)
        return np.array([[cos, -1j * sin], [-1j * sin, cos]], dtype=dtype)

Example showing how I add a gate equivalence (decomposing the Qiskit RX() gate into the new basis using ZXZXZ decomposition):
    q = QuantumRegister(1, "q")
    rx_equivalence = QuantumCircuit(q)
    rx_equivalence.append(RZGate(np.pi / 2), [0])
    rx_equivalence.append(NativeRXppion2Gate(), [0])    # RX(π/2)
    rx_equivalence.append(RZGate(theta), [0])
    rx_equivalence.append(NativeRXnpion2Gate(), [0])    # RX(-π/2)
    rx_equivalence.append(RZGate(-np.pi / 2), [0])
    SessionEquivalenceLibrary.add_equivalence(RXGate(theta), rx_equivalence)

I define:

new classes for RX(±), RX(±/2) and ISWAP. I don't specify a new class for RZ as it is virtual on the target platform
gate equivalences for RX() (shown above) and ISWAP, but no other gates.

Original test circuit:
Original input circuit
Circuit compiled to the new basis using quilc:
Circuit translated using quilc
Circuit compiled to the new basis using qiskit:
Circuit translated using qiskit
